# Chatter Rest API - Detect if Current User is Admin

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups, chatter-rest-api

If you want to join a private Chatter group via the Chatter REST API you're supposed to send a POST request to:

`/services/data/<<Version>>/chatter/groups/<<GroupId>>/members/requests`

with the body:

```
{
  "userId" : "me"
}
```

Which is all well and good. However, if you're an Administrator (i.e. you have the Modify All Data permission) you don't have to request, you can just join which is via a different URL. If you hit the above URL as an Administrator you get this back:

> errorCode: NOT_MODIFIED
>
> message: Administrators should create memberships directly on the group instead of requesting memberships

So the quesiton is this: **does the Chatter REST API *itself* provide a means for you knowing which URL to hit in advance?**

I assume that somehow, somewhere it does, since the standard Salesforce UI shows "Join" if you're an Administrator, as opposed to "Ask to Join" if you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Organization resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_connect.htm) (GET /connect/organization) and inspect the `userSettings.canModifyAllData` property of the response to determine whether or not the user issuing the request is an admin user.

If the user is an admin user, POST to the [Group Members resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_groups_GroupMembers.htm) to join the group.

Comment: Didn't occur to me to look under /connect. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!